# Syntax for IF Statement in nginx

Tags: nginx, syntax, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have two different server_name in nginx.conf file:
First one as:

```
server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.nithinveer\.com$;
    location /
            {
                    proxy_pass http://192.168.6.190/Profiles/$subdomain/default.aspx$request_uri/;
                    access_log /var/log/nginx/true.log;
            }
```

Another one as

```
server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.nithinveer\.com\.(?<extension>)$;
            location /extension 
            {
                    proxy_pass      http://192.168.6.190;
                    access_log /var/log/nginx/false.log;
            }
```

Now the thing is I want to use both the server_name based on the  in the server_name. If there is no extension with the server_name it should go to first location. If there is an extension, it should go to second location.
But while running the nginx, it is not moving into the second server_name
Can anyone please find some solution for this...?
I thought a solution as(may be wrong).

```
server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.nithinveer\.com\.(?<extension>.+)$;
            if($<extension> == NULL)
             {
                   location /
                        {
                    proxy_pass http://192.168.6.190/Profiles/$subdomain/default.aspx$request_uri/;
                    access_log /var/log/nginx/true.log;
                         }
              }
              else
            {       location /
                        {
                          proxy_pass      http://192.168.6.190;
                          access_log /var/log/nginx/false.log;
            }
```

But the syntax with the if statement throws an error.

Comment: in if condition, you shouldn't need '<' for extension variable, it can be just $extension.

Comment: and try after removing '\.' after com

Answer (score 5):

There's no ***else*** directive in nginx.
Also, you don't need to duplicate the location either.

try this:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+).nithinveer\.com(?<extension>\..+)$;

    location / {
            This will match hosts terminating with ".com"
            if ($extension = "")
              {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.6.190/Profiles/$subdomain/default.aspx$request_uri/;
                access_log /var/log/nginx/true.log;
              } 

            This will match hosts with something after ".com", e.g: "foo.nithinveer.com.me", the $extension will be ".me"
            if ($extension != "")
              {                    
                proxy_pass      http://192.168.6.190;
                access_log /var/log/nginx/false.log;
              }                

          }
}
```

Also, consider that [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

This is the version with a *safe* usage of it:

```
server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+).nithinveer\.com(?<extension>\..+)$;
    location / {
        error_page 418 = @with_extension;

        #This will match hosts with something after ".com", 
        # e.g: "foo.nithinveer.com.me", the $extension will be ".me"
        if ($extension != "")
          {                    
            return 418;
          }                

        #  This will match hosts terminating with ".com"       
        proxy_pass http://192.168.6.190/Profiles/$subdomain/default.aspx$request_uri/;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/true.log;

      }

    location @with_extension {        
        proxy_pass      http://192.168.6.190;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/false.log;  
    }
```

Comment: Can you merge those two server_names as a single one as if is evil with the same functionality as mentioned above

Comment: which two server_names? my updated answer has only one. The evil part is having something other than "return" or "rewrite" inside the if block.

Comment: What about a `map "$extension" $is_extension_empty`. Then use this value in the server block with `if ($is_extension_empty) { return 418 }` , putting that if outside the location?

I know, `if + return` in location aren't bad, but still if I can I tend to avoid them otherwise sooner or later, due to time constraints, one puts something else inside that if.